# JodaTime dd-MMM-yyyy Pattern Exception

Tags: java, formatting, jodatime

I have the following code

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy").withLocale(Locale.US);       
formatter.parseDateTime("10-23-2012");
```

Why am I getting the following exception?

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "10-23-2012" is malformed at "23-2012"
```

After reading the javadoc, I still can figure this out. The lowercase d (day of month) is supposed the represent minimum number of digits, but according to the exception it is getting truncated? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `dd-MM-yyyy`. Notice only two M's. Moreover, to parse `10-23-2012`, the format should be `MM-dd-yyy`

**Examples**

MMM = Feb, Jul etc.

MM = 02, 07 etc.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I also ran the code and did get an exception with the original format. MM-dd-yyy was exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are three month characters in `dd-MMM-yyyy` but only two in `10-23-2012`.

It gets worse.  Your middle digits appear to be a day, not a month; and you probably want something like "OCT" there anyway.